# Cordova ANDROID_HOME not found even already been added to environmental variables

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Lately I can perform cordova commands successfully such as

> cordova build --release android

But now it fails, saying `ANDROID_HOME not found` even I already added it on the windows environmental variables (below image)

[image]

I even tried to set the ANDROID_HOME and SDK tools, platform-tools path via windows command running as a administrator even it was already been set on the path.

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\UI-UX-PC1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
set PATH=C:\Users\UI-UX-PC1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
set PATH=C:\Users\UI-UX-PC1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
```

but no luck at all, any help, ideas please?

below is my cordova app `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <widget id="com.mobile.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Mobile App</name>
    <description>
        Mobile App
    </description>
    <author email="info@meme.com" href="https://www.meme.com">
        Meme mobile
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^5.0.0" /> </widget>
```

Comment: after setting variable please restart your system

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari: just did several times already but no luck

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is depreciated now use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. for more info follow this stackoverflow.com/a/55508862/6190043

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari correct, thank you for that. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ANDROID_HOME` is deprecated now instead of using `ANDROID_HOME` use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

as per Google android documentation -

`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` sets the path to the **SDK** installation directory. Once set, the value does not typically change, and can be shared by multiple users on the same machine. **ANDROID_HOME**, which also points to the **SDK** installation directory, is **deprecated**.

If you continue to use it, the following rules apply:

- If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined and contains a valid **SDK** installation, its value is used instead of the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.
- If `ANDROID_HOME` is not defined, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used.
- If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined but does not exist or does not contain a valid **SDK** installation, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used instead.

For details follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html#envar.)
I hope Its work for you